# React-admin: <Edit /> with custom username as id not displaying any form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

In react admin v3, I want to display an edit my profile form, it will contain

- Form to edit my `firstName`, `lastName`, `email`, `mobile`
- Form to edit my `password`

I want both form on the same page, with two submit button. I also want the saving to stay on that page.

This is what I have tried:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Edit, SimpleForm, TextInput } from 'ra-ui-materialui';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';

export default (props) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { username } = JSON.parse((localStorage.getItem('jwt') || '{}'));
  if (!username || username !==  props.id) {
    history.push('/');
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <Edit
      basePath="/"
      resource="profile"
      {...props}
    >
      <SimpleForm redirect="edit">
        <TextInput source="firstName" />
      </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
  );
};
```

For some reason, the form is performing the `ajax` request and the entity is retrieved but not injected in the `<SimpleForm />`, so it does not render anything:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hmm, wondering why `redirect='edit'` within the `SimpleForm`? Did you try removing that? About two forms being on the same page, are you looking at a solution without `<Tabs>`?

Comment: So far, we can just focus to one form without tabs, I am not even displaying the simplest form